# Waiting for $.post and .load() ajax calls to complete

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have some $.post() and $().load ajax calls and I'd like to execute a function when all of them have completed. I know the $.post() calls return a deferred object that I can in a when() call:

```
when(deferred1, deferred2, deferred3).done(function() {});
```

But how do I get a deferred object from the .load() call that I can use with when()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, `load` doesn't return a promise, it only accepts a `complete` callback. If you want to use it as part of a `when` invocation, you're going to have to build your own promise, and resolve/reject it inside the `complete` callback.

You're better off not using `load` at all (it really only saves you one line), or writing your own function which wraps it:

```
function load($el, url) {
  var dfd = $.Deferred();
  $el.load(url, function (responseText, textStatus, jqXHR)) {
    if (textStatus == 'success') {
      dfd.resolve();
    } else {
      dfd.reject();
    }
  })
  return dfd.promise();
}


$.when($.post(...), load($el, url), $post(...), load($el, url)).done(...)
```

Comment: Thanks for that.  You say that .load only saves you one line.  I guess you could do a $.post and then append the response to the element.  Is that what you were thinking of?